# Go net/http interface satisfaction

Tags: go, interface

I am trying to understand :

The `http.ServeMux` has the [Handle](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux.Handle) method which is used to register a new `http.Handler`.
So, you declare a method which satisfy the `http.Handler` interface by implementing `ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`) and register it.

Now the `http.ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error` method takes as its second parameter a handler, this confuse me because you pass it the `http.ServeMux` which got the different handlers types as an attribute [`m map[string]muxEntry`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=69181:69383#L2212) added during the call to [*mux.Handle](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=74967:75027#L2412)

Example

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

type customHandler struct {
    name string
}

func (c customHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "This is my first middleware in Go")
}

func main() {
    router := http.NewServeMux()
    customH := customHandler{"this is a test"}
    router.Handle("/", customH)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)

}
```

My question is how this works ?
does because `http.ServeMux` has Handler attributes, so it implement the interface ?

Comment: Yes. `http.ServeMux` is itself a handler.

Comment: `http.ServeMux` implements `Handler` because it has a matching `ServeHTTP` method defined.

Answer (score -2):

`http.ServeMux` [implement](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=62780:62827#L2408) the `http.ServeHTTP` method, hence it satisfy the `http.Handler` interface